# Python pandas dataframe convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    label = df['laebl']     # first column is label
    img = df['feature']     # second column is image (48*48), but it is a long string
```

the file format is like this

[image]

eg: img[0] is '70 80 82 72.....' is a string

however, I know it is possible to solve by converting to numpy array and using for loop

I'm wondering whether I can process in dataframe without for loop

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup**

```
import io
import pandas as pd

text = \
'''label,feature
0,70 80 82 72
0,151 150 147 155'''

buf = io.StringIO(text)

df = pd.read_csv(but)

   label          feature
0      0      70 80 82 72
1      0  151 150 147 155
```

---

Take the `feature` column, split it, convert it to a list, and re-load it into a new dataframe. From there, convert it to `int` with `astype` and add a column prefix.

```
v = pd.DataFrame(df.feature.str.split().tolist()).astype(int).add_prefix('X')
v.insert(0, 'label', df.label)

v

   label   X0   X1   X2   X3
0      0   70   80   82   72
1      0  151  150  147  155
```

Comment: @Achaca Sure... `.rename(columns=lambda x: 'X')`  instead of `.add_prefix(...)`